# Is the word "refueling" ever used in the US in a sense of filling up a gas tank of a car?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage, non-native-english

I need to proofread a text about statistical analysis of the average time drivers spend on gas stations. The text was not written by a native English speaker. I'm not a native speaker either, but a frequent use of the word "refueling" throughout this text struck me as weird. Some examples:

> *"Do the gas stations with the longest refueling times differ from the rest?"*
>
> *"Those lengthy refueling times aren’t just happening at one gas station."*
>
> *"Since they aren’t actually refueling visits, they don’t count toward our research."*
>
> *"By including stations with such entries in the data set, we risk incorrectly evaluating the refueling duration."*
>
> *"What remains is enough to calculate the average refueling time."*
>
> *"Most of the gas stations have shifted to the refueling time in range of 150 to 300 seconds"*

I asked for advice from Americans I know, and they told me that the word "refueling" indeed does sound strange in this context. They suggested me to use "gas refill" or "fill up", or at least "fuel stop". It sounds like a good suggestion, but when I tried googling the phrase "refueling time", I found quite a lot of hits, including some articles that seem to be close in context. I'll probably go with the suggestions given, but I'd like to hear if anyone has any more advice/opinion on this.

Comment: Refuel: 
in American English

- Transitive -
(Word forms: reˈfueled or reˈfuelled, reˈfueling or reˈfuelling)
1.  to supply again with fuel
- Intransitive - 
2.  to take on a fresh supply of fuel.  - https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/refuel

Comment: It doesn't sound strange, exactly, to my American ears, but informally one would use "fill up" or "fill up the tank" or "fill the tank" or, simply, "get gas." But in the clinical sense it is being used in your text it seems unexceptional and unexceptionable.

Comment: That last sentence is ungrammatical.  The first might be better as: “Are the gas stations with the longest refuelling times different from the rest?”

Comment: Not at all strange.

Comment: @Robusto "Refuelling" to my mind is more associated with aircraft. Like you, I don't think we use it for cars "fill" or "fill up" being the usual terms. Of course we don't call it "gas". I have heard Americans talk about "gassing the car" - which raises a smile here.

Comment: Fill up is more restrictive than refueling.  If a driver added 3 gallons but didn't fill the tank, we would't call that a fill up.  Refuel is a tiny bit strange, but it is accurate and it will be inderstood.

Comment: Suggest you search on refueling at a gas station.  You'll get lots of hits that show you how others use it.

Comment: *Refuel* is a verb. Of course we can turn any verb into an adjective as has been done in your examples. But if you need a temporary adjective, the noun phrase *gas pump* works best in all your examples: *Do the gas stations with the longest gas pump times differ from the rest? Since they aren’t actually gas pump visits, they don’t count toward our research. By including stations with such entries in the data set, we risk incorrectly evaluating the gas pump duration. What remains is enough to calculate the average gas pump time.*

Comment: @TinfoilHat Yes, good point. Actually, one of the reasons why this word struck me as weird is that it is occasionally used as a noun. For example: _Let's see how many refuels this gas station had._ I assume that even if "refueling" as a verb or an adjective is not weird, "refuel" as a noun still is, right? I'll use "gas pump" whenever they use a noun then.

Comment: @Robusto Thanks for reassuring me that it's not as weird as I initially thought. Noun cases aside, I'll probably keep them as they are then. That makes my job easier.

Comment: *Refuel* as noun is very, very weird. Maybe you could use *refueling* the gerund as a noun: *Let's see how many refuelings this gas station had.* But even that is very weird.